# Route Attribute Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, routeattribute

Trying to use a [Route] attribute in my MVC app, per this article:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

```
[Route("Error/{type?}")]
    public ActionResult Error(string type)
    {
        if (type == "Duplicate")
        {
            ViewBag.ErrorDetails = "There is already a redirect using that Vanity URL and Domain.";
        }

        if (type == "Unknown")
        {
            ViewBag.ErrorDetails = "An unknown error has occured. Probably your fault too.";
        }

        return View();
    }
```

I have MapMvcAttributeRoutes in RouteConfig.cs

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
    }
}
```

I get a 404 when browsing to /Admin/Error/Duplicate but /Admin/Error?type=Duplicate works fine.

In addition to `[Route("Error/{type}")]` I have tried `[Route("Admin/Error/{type})]` and `[Route("{type})]` but no luck.  I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` need to be before your `routes.MapRoute(..)` definitions

Comment: Changed it to

'        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

        }'

And still get a 404.

Comment: provide full controller code pls. that [Route("Admin/Error/{type})] works very well for me.